# Symfony 2: why form_theme not working for FOS_User registration template?

Tags: forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have installed FOSUserBundle, customized template MyBundle::User:registration.html.twig with content

```
{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block `form_widget_simple` %}
Hey! I wanna replace all your text fields in this form!
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
   <h1>Registration</h1>
   {{form(form)}}
{% endblock content %}
```

My goal is to replace all text fields (`<input type="text">`) in my `form` with contents of block `form_widget_simple`. Code above is not working: all fields are not replaced. But replacements is correct when I copy this code into another template (not related to FOSUserBundle). What is dark magic in the FOS User that prevents my replacements (or in my code)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the documentation (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md) and correctly registered your bundle as a `FOSUserBundle` ?

Make sure to do the following modification, as written in the doc :

```
// src/Acme/UserBundle/AcmeUserBundle.php
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did. Everything works fine except this strange behaviour with form_theme

Comment: I'm not on my personal computer right now so I didn't try what is following. Can you try to display a single `<input type="text"/>` field instead of the whole form? Then, if it doesn't work, try to use the block `text_widget` instead of `form_widget_simple`. PS: You can normally remove the single quotes, they are not needed here.

Comment: @psylosss, what about replacing the line `{% block form_widget_simple %}` by `{% block text_widget %}`, for instance?
And to do exactly the same as the cookbook, replace the `{% endblock %}` statement by `{% endblock text_widget %}`